# How to design a view consisting of a table row ,label and dropdownlist

Tags: iphone

I am not getting how to design such a layput from interface builder.What i am planning is that :make two subviews in a single view
In one view put uitable view
and in another view put from and to labels and corresponding dropdownlists

[image]

i am not having any idea on how to do that.Can i do all above stuff in a single UItableView but how?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no drop downliss in iPhone, you will have to use  UIPickerView class, called picker views, that use a spinning-wheel to show one or more sets of values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put it in a tableview. I also don't know what that stuff on bottom is, perhaps a tabbar? In that case you should use a tabbar with 5 segments. The dropdownlist could be a custom button, if you click on it, you get a new screen with a spinning wheel. If my guess on the arrow on the right is correct, clicking it should show you a table view. In that case I suggest to use the navigation bar. That way, a user can easily navigate back and forth. In the method viewWillAppear, you can use an update to properly show the information in the table.

Comment: !Thanks for reply.I am able to navigate in tabbar and nothing to do with that one.I am having stuff in creating view above the tabbar.And as you assume(about arrow on right side) i am able to navigate to other class.But only stuff is in dropdownlist/picker.The data in pickerview has to be come dynamically either from some datasource may be database or even from array it is to be decided.Can i bind data from any source to my uipicker view.

Comment: @Maddy ofcourse you can. The class you'd like to get the data from, should be linked to that tableview. Two things should be done: 1. Connect the tableView with the class, and set the class as the datasource. And 2. the class that should be the datasource, needs to have the following line in the .h file: `@interface nameController:UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource> {`

Comment: @Maddy ah I was way to eager to type a response. For the UIPickerView, you should type pickerName.dataSource = <classname containing the array with items for in the picker>. For example, if you have it in the same controller, you should type `pickerName.dataSource = self;`